# Showing Subcategory's Name and Link Instead of Parent Category's

Tags: php, categories

Right now my code is displaying the category name and link. But if an article is in a subcategory, I want to display the subcategory's name and link instead of the parent category's name and link. For some reason though it's still just showing the parent category. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong with the code?

```
    <?php $category_separator = "";
foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
     $parentcat = $childcat->category_parent;
     if( $parentcat != 0 ) echo '<span class="' . get_cat_name($parentcat) .'"><a href="' . get_category_link($parentcat) . '">' .get_cat_name($parentcat) .'</a></span>';
     else echo '' . $category_separator . '<span class="'. $childcat->cat_name .'"><a href="' . get_category_link($childcat) .'">' . $childcat->cat_name . '</a></span>';
    $category_separator = " / ";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Little change:

```
<?php $category_separator = "";
foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
     $parentcat = $childcat->term_id;
     if( $parentcat != 0 ) echo '<span class="' . get_cat_name($parentcat) .'"><a href="' . get_category_link($parentcat) . '">' .get_cat_name($parentcat) .'</a></span>';
     else echo '' . $category_separator . '<span class="'. $childcat->cat_name .'"><a href="' . get_category_link($childcat) .'">' . $childcat->cat_name . '</a></span>';
    $category_separator = " / ";
}
?>
```

Actually you were getting the parent category id

```
 $parentcat = $childcat->category_parent;
```

Instead of that you need to get actual sub category id

```
$parentcat = $childcat->term_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it still shows the parent category too. Is there a way to hide the parent if the article is part of a child category?

Answer (score 0):

Only showing the child category

```
global $post;    
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
            {
                if($term->parent!=0)
                {
                    $pcategory = get_term( $term->parent, 'product_cat' );
                    $categories[] = $pcategory->slug;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the else condition, you are using `$childcat->cat_name` to get the subcategory name, but `cat_name` is not a valid property. You should use name instead.
you are using `get_category_link($childcat)` to get the link for the subcategory, but get_category_link() expects a category `ID`, not an `object`. You should use `$childcat->term_id` to get the `category ID`

```
$category_separator = "";
foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
    $parentcat = $childcat->category_parent;
    if ($parentcat != 0) {
        echo '<span class="' . get_cat_name($childcat->term_id) .'"><a href="' . get_category_link($childcat->term_id) . '">' . get_cat_name($childcat->term_id) .'</a></span>';
    } else {
        echo '' . $category_separator . '<span class="'. $childcat->name .'"><a href="' . get_category_link($childcat->term_id) .'">' . $childcat->name . '</a></span>';
    }
    $category_separator = " / ";
}
```